# underscore.js , iterating over an array to list all index for a specific value

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array in which I am tryingg to iterate to get ALL indexes when a true value is found for a key

```
    sheet.headings = [
      {
        "label": "SheetId",
        "access": "R",
        "hidden": true,
        "position": "left",
        "input_type": "text"
      },
      {
        "label": "Moteur Affichage",
        "access": "W",
        "hidden": false,
        "position": "left",
        "input_type": "text",
        "value_type": "text"
      },
      {
        "label": "Navigateur",
        "access": "W",
        "hidden": true,
        "position": "left",
        "input_type": "text",
        "value_type": "text"
      }
    ]
```

I can only get the first index, not all of the  ( I should get [0,2]

```
    var column_hidden = _.findIndex(sheet.headings, function(col) {
      return col.hidden === true ;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can achieve this using the map and filter functions of Array. Something like:

```
sheet.headings.map(function(e,i){
    if (e.hidden) return i;
}).filter(function(e){
    return typeof e != 'undefined';
})
```

First you get an array with the index than matches hidden==true and then you filter to remove the objects that are undefined.

Comment: the 'ruby' way..  thanks a lot it's giving the expected result.... I was too narrow-minded, trying to use underscore.js functions....